# Create Explorer like view in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I want to create an additional **Folder tree view** in the Explorer **container** with an extension, so I can see other directories and files that aren't related to the opened workspace.

I also want to keep the look and feel of the additional tree view like the original Explorer tree view (icons, menus, etc.)

Is there a built-in way to use tree view that supports showing files from the file system as the explorer does?

Comment: if you make the TreeItems based on URI's VSC will display them like the explorer with the file icons

Comment: File icons are only one aspect. You cannot display your tree items in different colors, you cannot have the same context menu etc.

Comment: @rioV8, I see, but I want a tree view that looks and feels like the original Explorer, and as Mike Lischke said, file icons only aren't enough. Is there any way to inherit the existing tree view or something?

Answer (score 0):

In the `package.json`, you can contribute additional views to the explorer, like:

```
"views": {
  "explorer": [
    {
      "id": "id123",
      "name": "name"
    }
  ]
}
```

You can then use the `vscode.window.createTreeView("id123")` command to add a tree view to the view.

There is an API description of the tree view [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#TreeView%3CT%3E)

Comment: While this allows to add another view, it doesn't answer the question how to maintain the same look and feel like the other views.